# Nvidia GeForce GT540M Ubuntu 18.04 overheating

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, overheating

I have an Acer 4830TG notebook, with freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04. All seems to be fine, but it gets overheated.

I have the following output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.116                Driver Version: 390.116                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 540M     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   69C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    238MiB /  1985MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also have `tlp` installed. I tried to purge and re-install the driver, but it did not help. With X.org X server it is also overheating.

So I would be very grateful for any suggestions that could help solve the problem.

Comment: I had same issue on Lenovo laptop with Nvidia card. I installed bumblebee and everything works great now. No overheating or RAM issues. Here is the link I used - https://float-middle.com/ubuntu-18-04-steam-and-nvidia-390/

Answer (score 0):

Which OS were you running prior to Ubuntu? Were there any temp problems with that OS? Here is a link to install Psensor which will allow you view the temps in an applet at the top of the screen.

[Install Psensor](https://itsfoss.com/check-laptop-cpu-temperature-ubuntu/)

Usually these problems are caused by blockages in the ducting of the machines air passages. Do you have a dog or cat that sheds? Is the machine fairly dusty. 9 times out of 10 cleaning the fan and air intake ports with compressed air will solve these problems as will disassembling the bottom of the laptop and then manually cleaning the debris out. Could you please try that and report back with the results.

Comment: I had 14.04 before, it was fine. I have `sensors` installed, and the temperature seems to be really high

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +90.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +88.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +90.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Comment: Deleted my comment, just realized those are in Celsius, not farenheit. Can you post the output of the "top" command so I can which processes are running? Also, do you hear the fan audibly running? Were you able to remove the bottom and clean it out (even if your confident that its clean, just take a quick look).

Comment: Yeah, but the notebook is really hot, and playing online videos in full screen makes it really slow

Comment: Its slowing down so it doesnt die completely. At those temps though, it wont be long. Take a look at my previous comment and let me know what you find.

Comment: here is the outout of `top`

751404 110808  74216 S   5.3  2.8   0:15.90 chrome                                                                    
3985736 308568  96308 S   4.6  7.9   9:56.73 gnome-shell                                                               
810240 151952  82616 S   3.6  3.9   1:49.14 chrome                                                                    
1114904 170904 108148 S   3.3  4.4   0:23.55 rambox

Comment: 503388  11728   8808 S   2.0  0.3   0:01.02 udisksd                                                                   
898696 201908 115532 S   1.7  5.2   2:47.47 chrome                                                                    
397976  83548  52448 S   1.0  2.1   3:08.27 Xorg

Comment: I just googled your laptop model and overheating. It looks like they tend to do this a lot regardless of the OS. I recommend you doing the same search. The best I could come up with is thermal paste issues. One guy cleaned and lubed his fan, but didnt see any positive results so maybe the passages arent blocked. I'm really sorry man. i was hoping there would be a quick fix here.

Comment: np, as I started fixing this, I thought I would also be easy, now seems it is not :)